# GULP LESS Imports not working in gulp-less npm

Tags: npm, gulp, lumen, gulp-less

Having used Gulp all the time for 2 last years, I've suddenly got a problem with the less file imports and just can not resolve it.

I've tried more then 5 combinations, such as from SmashingMagazine, from gulp-less homepage, etc... none worked for me.

The problem is (error log in console output):

```
C:\wamp\www\lumenframe>gulp less
[10:23:25] Using gulpfile C:\wamp\www\lumenframe\Gulpfile.js
[10:23:25] Starting 'less'...
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] '/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css' wasn't found. Tried - /bower_components/animate.css/animate.c
ss,bower_components\bootstrap\less\bower_components\animate.css\animate.css,bower_components\animate.css\bower_components\animate.css\animate
.css,bower_components\font-awesome\less\bower_components\animate.css\animate.css in file C:\wamp\www\lumenframe\bower_components\assets\l
ess\appstrap.less line no. 43
```

Gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
// Init Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Dependencies
var less = require('gulp-less'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-uglify');

// Folder paths
var jsdir = './bower_components/assets/js/',
    jspub = './public/assets/js/',
    lessdir = './bower_components/assets/less/',
    lesspub = './public/assets/css/';

// LESS compiler
gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src(lessdir + 'frontend.less')
        .pipe(less({
            compress: true,
            paths: [
                './bower_components/bootstrap/less/',
                './bower_components/animate.css/',
                './bower_components/font-awesome/less/'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 versions', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(lesspub));
});

// Concatenate and Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsdir + '*.js')
        .pipe(concat('appstrap.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jspub))
        .pipe(rename('appstrap.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jspub));
});

// Filewatcher for changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(jsdir + '*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(lessdir + '*.less', ['less']);
});

// Default Task combination
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

All files are in their proper place, so they exists. And once I do `@import appstrap.less`, it comes out with the error **Potentially unhandled rejection [2].

frontend.less looks like this:

```
// Core source files of the whole frontend plugins
@import (once) "appstrap.less";

.btn{
    color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
}
```

Any visible errors ?